# Set range for sort function

Tags: vba, excel, sorting, match

I am trying to set the range of the column for the sort function.

However, the range starts from a certain row which i used the match function to find and ends at where ever the cells is empty. How do I go around doing that?

Its on the line:

```
Sheet3.Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range("G" & v & "G" & v.End(xlDown)), 
    SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlDescending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
```

Thanks for your help in advance!

```
Sheet3.Sort.SortFields.Clear
v = Application.Match("GND", Sheet3.Range("C:C"), 0)
Sheet3.Range("A" & v & ":K" & v).Select
Sheet3.Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
Sheet3.Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range("G" & v & "G" & v.End(xlDown)), 
SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlDescending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
Sheet3.Sort.Apply
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no need to use `Select` (it only slows down your code run-time), try the code below:

```
Option Explicit

Sub SortRange()

Dim v As Variant
Dim Rng As Range

With Sheet3
    .Sort.SortFields.Clear
    v = Application.Match("GND", .Range("C:C"), 0) '<-- make sure Match is not returning an #ERROR
    Set Rng = .Range(.Range("A" & v & ":K" & v), .Range("A" & v & ":K" & v).End(xlDown))

   Rng.Sort Key1:=.Range("G" & v), Order1:=xlDescending, DataOption1:=xlSortNormal
End With

End Sub
```

[image]